# Jquery access function outside of var

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to access my newTokenText function which is outside of my var from within my var.

```
(function ($) {

// Default settings
    var DEFAULT_SETTINGS = {
        resultsFormatter: function(item, resultSize, index){
            return "<li>" + newTokenText(item[this.propertyToSearch], resultSize, index) + "</li>"
        },
    }

   init: function(url_or_data_or_function, options) {
        var settings = $.extend({}, DEFAULT_SETTINGS, options || {});
   }


    function newTokenText(value, resultSize, index) {
        if(settings.newTokenText && resultSize == index) {
            return value + " " + settings.newTokenText;
        }
        return value;
    }

    function populate_dropdown (query, results) {
        if(results && results.length) {               
            var resultSize = results.length - 1;
            $.each(results, function(index, value) {
                var this_li = settings.resultsFormatter(value, resultSize, index);
            }
        }
    }
```

getting error, newTokenText is not a function. Could somebody tell me how to access this function?

Comment: Have you tried declaring newTokenText() *before* calling it?

Comment: Can you just swap the `function` and `variable` declaration as a test case? I mean declare function before variable.

Comment: @SurrealDreams actually that shouldn't matter so long as he never **calls** `obj.resultsFormatter` until after `newTokenText` is defined.

Comment: Where is your `settings` assignment and how does it look?

Comment: I added additional code.

Comment: I just moved my newTokenText into my default settings variable and it works fine.